# The command timeout does not throw

Tags: c#, npgsql

```
 private void NpgSqlGetContracts(IList<Contract> con)
    {
        var conn = (NpgsqlConnection)Database.GetDbConnection();

        List<Contract> contracts = new List<Contract>();

        using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM \"Contracts\";", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 1;

            cmd.Prepare();

            int conCount= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    contracts.Add(MapDataReaderRowToContract(reader));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I have this code to try the command timeout in postgres, I have try debug it locally with break point in visual studio. I try both ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteReader The query took **more than 1 second** to load all data (I have above 3 millions rows here). But the **command timeout is set to 1** second. I wonder why it does not throw any exception here, What did I configured wrong here?

Thank you :)

Comment: "CommandTimeout has no effect when the command is executed against a context connection (a SqlConnection opened with "context connection=true" in the connection string)" - could it be your case?

Comment: If I correctly interpret the second note in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout), every `.Read()` call resets the timeout. So in your case, as long as each separate Read is done within 1 second, you will not get a timeout

Comment: You should probably dispose your `conn` object, I hope you're not caching it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hans-keﬆing wrote above, the command timeout isn't cumulative for the entire command, but rather for each individual I/O-producing call (e.g. `Read`). In that sense, it's meant to help with queries running for too long (without producing any results), or network issues.

You may also want to take a look at PostgreSQL's [`statement_timeout`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html), which is a PG-side timeout for the entire command. It too has its issues, and Npgsql never sets it implicitly for you - but you can set it yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your response :). I have 1 more question, what about the BeginBinaryImport where do we set the command timeout? in the connection string? cause I saw in SqlServer it has BulkCopyTimeout when doing SqlBulkCopy so we can set the command time out there

Comment: Since 5.0, the binary exporter and importer types have a new Timeout property for this - https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1328.